# Ruby: overload operator behaviour for some cases only

Tags: ruby, methods, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

My question is: how do I overload an operator on a builtin class (such as Integer.new.+) but only for some cases, depending on the class of the second operand

This is the behaviour I'm looking for:

```
myObject = myClass.new
1 + myObject #=> special behaviour
1 + 2        #=> default behaviour (3)
```

For example, in Python I would define a `__radd__` method on myClass to override case 1.

I've tried using `super` but apparently `Numeric` doesn't have operator methods.

Ideally, what I'm looking for is a way to extract the `+` method and rename it.

Like this:

```
class Integer
  self.plus = self.+  # you know what i mean, I don't know how else to express this.
                      # I also know that methods don't work like this, this is just to
                      # illustrate a point.
  def + other
    other.class == myClass ? special behaviour : self.plus other
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: There's no direct equivalent of `__radd__` but `coerce` is the closest Ruby method you can get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both approaches posted here so far are a legacy Rails way, which is *plain wrong*. It relies on the fact that the class has no method called `plus` *and* nobody will reopen the class to create a method called `plus`. Otherwise things will go mad.

The correct solution is [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend):

```
Integer.prepend(Module.new do
  def + other
    case other
    when Fixnum then special_behaviour
    else super(other)
    end
  end
end)
```

Comment: Why did you use a case statement instead of an if else? Is it faster?

Comment: It is more readable and easily extendable with more branches. Also, please note that the above will match any descendant of `Fixnum`, as opposite to `other.class == Fixnum` that matches `Fixnum` instances only. To match all descendants by class one should use `other.class <= Fixnum`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can override the behavior of almost anything in the standard library to achieve an outcome, but that's going to hurt understanding of the code and come back to bite you sometime in the future.

In this particular case, `Fixnum#+` is designed to take a numeric value and return a numeric result. If we want to define our own classes to interact with `Fixnum#+`, we need to understand the design contract and adhere to it.

The general convention in Ruby is to use duck typing. We don't care about the class of the object, we just care whether it behaves like / can be converted to the object we want. Eg:

```
class StringifiedNumber
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  # String#+ calls to_str on any object passed to it

  def to_str
    # replace with number to string parsing logic
    "one hundred"
  end
end 

> "total: " + StringifiedNumber.new(100)
=> "total: one hundred"
```

Things are a bit more complex with numbers since you may mix integers, floats, complex numbers, etc. The convention to handle this is to define a `coerce` method which returns two elements of the same type which are then used to perform the requested operation.

```
class NumberfiedString
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def to_i
    # replace with complicated natural language parsing logic
    100
  end

  def +(other_numberfied_string)
    NumberfiedString.new(self.to_i + other_numberfied_string.to_i)
  end

  # For types which are not directly supported,
  # Fixnum#+(target) will call the equivalent of 
  # target.coerce[0] + target.coerce[1] 

  def coerce(other)
    [NumberfiedString.new(other.to_s), self]
  end
end

> NumberfiedString.new("one hundred") + NumberfiedString.new("one hundred")
=> #<NumberfiedString:0x007fadbc036d28 @string=200>

> 100 + NumberfiedString.new("one hundred") 
=> #<NumberfiedString:0x007fadbc824c88 @string="200">
```

---

To answer OP's follow up question:

> Is there no equivalent to Python's radd and related methods? (Where,
>   if the first operand doesn't support the operation or the types, the
>   second operand takes over)

```
class MyClass
  def +(other)
    puts "called +"
  end

  def coerce(other)
    [self, other]
  end
end

> 1 + MyClass.new
called +
=> nil
```

Comment: `@string=200` in the printed result suggests, that you probably need `initialize` to accept both strings _and_ integers. Current code is simply broken after first call to `:+`.

Comment: Yes, that should be resolved if this was actual code. I chose to keep this contrived example short to illustrate the mechanism.

Comment: This is hardly a ruby approach to implementing this kind of behaviour. Also, I never saw (and honestly I do not understand any reason for) `coerce` method returning two values.

Comment: This should help you understand it: https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2011/01/25/class-coercion-in-ruby

Comment: This is a redundant (read: inappropriate) way of doing a coercion. Passing `self` through just makes no sense. All robust implementations of coercion simply accept a single parameter, namely the type. This is a wrong advice in a nutshell.

Comment: So you're saying Ruby's implementation of coercion is not robust? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-coerce

Comment: @mudasobwa: With all due respect, it looks like you don't understand `coerce`. This answer works fine and is much cleaner than any other solution here. If you don't absolutely need to touch `Integer#+`, don't touch it, even with `prepend`. Ruby `coerce` is also the closest method to Python `__radd__`, even though it applies to all numerical operators, not just `+`.

Comment: @EricDuminil that’s truly possible I don’t understand ruby `coerce`. I can’t think of a single reason to return a tuple back. Yes, to me it looks weird and I accept that might be because I am not a rubyist. The reason “it’s how it’s implemented in ruby” does not sound as a proof either, there are many things that are done in ruby ...hhm not in the best way.

Comment: @mudasobwa: The whole purpose of `coerce` is to convert 2 objects that aren't compatible by default into 2 objects on which you can use numerical operators. It needs to return a pair back : one of them usually being `self`, the other one being converted to an object compatible with `self`. To be fair, the documentation on `coerce` is almost non-existent and not very clear.

Comment: @EricDuminil I believe I understand what coercion is for :). It’s not necessarily to be for numerical operations, e.g. it is heavily used in [`dry-validation`](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/) for accepting form parameters and converting them on the fly to what type is expected. I still do not see any reason to pass the `self` through. In the ideal world that might be used for sophisticated coercion (`1 + '1½' #⇒ 2.5`) but it’s neither robust nor implemented for anything due to SRP (`Integer` should not depend on `Float` implementation.)

Comment: @mudasobwa: Do you have a link to a specific part of `dry-validation`? AFAIK, Ruby's standard `coerce` is only defined and used for `+ - * /`, and it requires 2 objects. There might be alternative implementations, but it's not the `coerce` used in this answer.

Comment: `coerce` is basically inversion of control to allow any class to interact with numeric operators. `Money`, `Coordinate`, `Area`, whatever domain concepts we need. It allows us to do things like `3 * Money.new(1) == Money.new(3)` instead of constraining us to only `Money.new(1) * 3`.

Comment: About the follow up: Can I only coerce for some operators (i.e. have different behaviours for different operators)? I'm asking because if I do `1 < myObject`, it coerces to `myObject < 1` which is the opposite

Comment: @AsoneTuhid No, the idea for `coerce` is that it should not need to be aware of operators. For this case, you can cast `1` into an object of your own type, i.e. `coerce` should return `[MyClass.new(other), self]`.